# Your Web Site is not very helpful

Tags: discussion, bible

I asked you, what I thought was a valid question. "Why did the many miracles stop being administered by the Apostle after Jesus's ascendance"? Why did you have to come back with a statement about me having to have more faith? This infers that I don't have enough. I am learning to have my Christian walk encompass more knowledge about the times before and after Jesus’s presence with us on Earth.
I believe that you do little to portray a friendly, helpful, web site. I will endeavour to pass on your judgemental views about helping new Christians, and hopefully you will not have to exercise your ignorance or, your arrogance to me or my friends in the future.
Mike

Comment: What question? Please add a link to it

Comment: Be aware that this website is run largely by the people who show up. And the comments are also made by the people who show up. Sometimes the comments are off-base. If you see one that you think is off-base, you can flag it and a moderator will look at it and delete it if it's inappropriate.

Answer (score 4):

#### How odd.  I find this site immensely helpful.

At this site, I get to learn how diverse Christian experience is, how rich and yet different much Christian theology is, and I get to learn it from those who are experts in that immense subject that is *Christianity*.  I don't come here for "the truth" (because only Jesus is the way, the truth, and the life) but for understanding, and for discovering what we have in common as Christians, and for where we differ.  (The disputes are as old as Paul and Peter's disagreements, see *Galatians*).

This site is rich with the treasure of understanding.

Christianity.SE has a particular focus, and a purpose, being part of the family of SE sites.  It has grown to learn, as a community, what its strengths and what its limitations are.

[It does not try to be all things to all people.](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6114/24204)  If you will not spend the time and effort [to understand what we are about, and how we are different](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/24204), then it may not be the best site for you just now.  Perhaps later in your journey of faith this Q&A site will be of more assistance/use to you, and your particular journey in faith.

Comment: Good answer.  I especially appreciate that you didn't just "send them off with a kiss goodbye" but informed them politely that now may not be the time, but some time the site may be useful to them, again.  Quick suggestion since I notice you are editing to be more grammatically correct: "those who are expert" should be pluralized as the word THOSE is plural--experts also should be.  I know it might be debatable since expert can be used as a level of proficiency, as in "I have become adept at my craft", but better to say experts. Also," grown to learn, as a community," is better as a clause. ;)

Comment: @user31124 Expert can go either way.  I intended to use it in the "level of proficiency" sense.  Will edit, good point.