# What is the meaning of this?

Tags: discussion

Please, I will like to know what kind of Christianity is going on in this place. Simple questions I keep asking here... And the focus is like this is not the kind of questions to ask. What is Christianity in this form all about? Am I in the wrong place for God sake?!!!

Comment: Please visit the help center (https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see what type of questions you can ask here: `Christianity Stack Exchange is for committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more. You may ask questions about any area of Christianity. Your own beliefs do not not preclude you from asking questions, but all questions must be directly related to Christianity.`

Comment: @depperm, please, are my questions not related to Christianity? And what do you mean by committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more?

Comment: This site is not teaching/preaching any type of Christianity exactly, rather it is a place where you can ask questions about a particular denomination, biblical basis of a belief, or a combination of the two. If you are interested in learning more about a particular denomination you can ask a question and if it isn't a duplicate question you will get an answer written by an expert in that particular denomination.

Comment: or as the help center puts it: `This site is not a church! It is neither sanctioned by any church nor sponsored as a ministry site. It is a secular site for asking and answering questions about Christianity. If you are more inclined to resent rather than celebrate the differences between different Christian traditions, then this may not be the site for you.`

Comment: @depperm, thank you very much. That notwithstanding, did I say the contrary of whatever history you have copied and pasted above there? Nope! So let me make it clearer to you again that my questions have nothing to do with any church and also, that I don't really care what Christian traditions any given Jack is from.
Thanks.

Comment: People shouldn't take pleasure in just downvoting others questions with no tangible reason. Questions that just need us to talk in a community... as followers of Christ, very simple. I read the whatever health center and my question does not violate it in any form.

Comment: Welcome, Yufenyuy, to the site. We deal in questions that can be objectively answered here, often of the form "What do X group of Christians believe about doctrine Y". It takes some getting used to, but if we answered questions about what is the truth, it would generate disputes. We do have a chat feature, where you can discuss personal viewpoints, but that would not be the place to seek specific advice, either.

Comment: ***People shouldn't take pleasure in just downvoting others questions with no tangible reason*** People should refrain from attempts at mind reading, and assuming malice where none is present.  You only get to make one first impression. If you mouse over the down vote button, you will read the text which tells you what a down vote means.  [Please read this to understand some of the boundaries of this SE site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6103/24204).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thank you. I know about hovering the down vote. I only get to make one first impression, thanks. But the question is "Am I seeking your first impression approval?" I don't think so, my brother. Thank you too for the link.

Comment: One other point, regarding complaining about how others vote, both opposes the general policy on voting, and bumps up against the [Be Nice](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy.   What this community has found out over the last five to seven years is that it takes a particular kind of structure and set of community norms to prevent arguments and inter-denominational bickering.  The limitations are in place to keep positive engagement foremost.  It takes a little getting used to (at least it did for me). *pax vobiscum*

Comment: Good! @KorvinStarmast. Very good, thank you. I also believe I already have 'pax'. Consequently, I need not any *pax vobiscum* wishes.

Comment: When I Muslim friend of mine offered that he wished for Allah's peace to be upon me, I took it in the spirit offered. ;)  Just a thought.  Best wishes in all things.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast thank you for the peaceful wishes. I wish you same.

Comment: I need more downvotes to my question above, please.

Answer (score 3):

I see your question was moved out of Christianity Stack Exchange into Christianity Meta and that this question has been given a "discussion" tag:

> "The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus."

I am new to Christianity Stack Exchange and it takes a while to navigate around the site to understand how it works.  Frankly, asking questions is harder than answering them!  However, what I have observed is that this site is for seriously minded folks who are not interested in pushing their own particular beliefs but who genuinely want non-judgmental and objective answers that can be supported by external sources and/or the Bible itself.

If you go back to the Christianity Stack Exchange site and click on "tags" you will discover a wide range of Christian-based subjects that attract questions and answers.  It also helps to open up the "Questions" link to see what sort of questions attract answers - and what sort of questions don't make the grade!

Once you've framed your question (to comply with the guidelines) you can then find the appropriate tag/s to attach to your question.  I'm still learning how to do this properly.  For example, perhaps I should just have added a comment rather than give an answer.  Making mistakes is often the best way to learn, though.  I do so hope you will persevere because this site contains a lot of really good, well researched information about Christianity in general and various denominations in particular.

Comment: Thanks, @Lesley. This sounds friendly and less harsh to me. I could just upvote but I like to post my opinion clearly.